# How to fetch Data From JSON

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-layout, android-listview

I have following data from JSON

```
{
        "MenuName": "starter dish",
        "SubMenu": [
            "pizza dish1",
            "pizza dish2"
        ],
        "Price": [
            "100",
            "110"
        ]
    },
```

From here i can easily fetch data from "`Menuname`" key as starter dish but when I fetch data from "`Submenu`" I get whole string as `["pizza dish1", "pizza dish2"]`.

Please suggest me way to differentiate both `pizza dish1  and pizza dish2`

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/2427543

Comment: @vdwijngaert I am getting price from parsing but whole string i am getting is both the values. need to differentiate them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Submenu` and `Price` is not String it is `JSONArray` so you will need to use `for-loop` to get all values from `Submenu` `JSONArray` as:

```
JSONArray jsonsubmenu=yourjsonobject.getJSONArray("Submenu");

  for(int i=0;i < jsonsubmenu.length();i++){     
     // get all values from jsonsubmenu JSONArray..
      String str_value=jsonsubmenu.optString(i);
      ....
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
          for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
             jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("SubMenu");
             }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [this link](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/) for creating POGO class for your response. It will automatically generate class for your response.

Use google [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) library to parse your response.

or you can simply create a JSON Array or Objects to parse it. in your case it is JSON Object or JSON arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There in that senarerio you have to use

```
    JSONArray _submenu = object.getJSONArray("SubMenu");
        for (int i = 0; i < _submenu.length(); i++) {
            String text = _submenu.getString(i);
        }
        JSONArray _price = object.getJSONArray("Price");
        for (int i = 0; i < _price.length(); i++) {
            String text = _price.getString(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve array values and store it in string[] and use them as per your need. i.e., as follows..

```
try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray jSubmenu = jObject.getJSONArray("SubMenu");
            subMenu = new String[jSubmenu.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < subMenu.length; i++) {
                subMenu[i] = jSubmenu.getString(i);
            }
            JSONArray jPrice = jObject.getJSONArray("Price");
            price = new String[jPrice.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
                price[i] = jPrice.getString(i);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw in a quickie - read up on, and use GSON.

For simple small jobs I find it is the best. Not the fastest running for complex, or long structures, but really quick on the dev side.

Here's the link: [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)