# Parsing data using JSON in android

Tags: java, android

I am parsing data using json object,and the data is also parsing from server,it shows in console but it got crash in emulator..

Here is my code:

```
public class jsonUtil {
    static HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

    public static HttpURLConnection openConnection() throws Exception {
        int responseCode = -1;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("url display");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-encoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty(
                    "Content-Length",
                    "" + Integer.toString("category=breaking_news&latitude=&longitude="
                                            .getBytes().length));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes("category=breaking_news&latitude=&longitude=");
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new Exception("Server not responding");
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            throw new Exception("Connection Time Out");
        } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException unknownHostException) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            throw new Exception("unknownHostException");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            throw new Exception("Error Occured");
        }
        return urlConnection;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> jsonParseList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> jsonParsing() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        JSONArray array;

        try {
            try {
                urlConnection = openConnection();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            if (buffer.toString() != null) {
                try {
                    array = new JSONArray(buffer.toString());
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String conv_title = jsonObject.getString("conv_title");
                        String content = jsonObject.getJSONObject("first_post")
                            .getString("content");
                        String creator = jsonObject.getJSONObject("first_post")
                            .getJSONObject("creator").getString("name");
                        Log.e("List Values", conv_title);
                        jsonParseList.add(conv_title);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonParseList;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

'  06:35:21.637: E/List Activity(795): []
05-30 06:35:21.687: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-30 06:35:21.697: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-30 06:35:21.717: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-30 06:35:21.927: I/Choreographer(795): Skipped 144 frames!  (795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-30 06:35:22.158: I/Choreographer(795): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-30 06:35:22.317: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-30 06:35:22.317: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-30 06:35:22.337: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-30 06:35:23.485: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_CONCURRENT freed 276K, 12% free 2894K/3288K, paused 69ms+3ms, total 134ms
05-30 06:35:23.642: E/List Values(795): Prime Minister Manmohan Singh to present UPA II report card today
: E/List Values(795): US, India pledge to collaborate on combating terrorism
05-30 06:35:23.652: E/List Values(795): US, India pledge to collaborate on combating terrorism
05-30 06:35:23.652: E/List Values(795): Pakistan's real motives exposed
05-30 06:35:23.652: E/List Values(795): Pakistan's real motives exposed
05-30 06:35:23.657: E/List Values(795): Rupee recovers marginally, up 6 paise in early trade
05-30 06:35:23.657: E/List Values(795): Rupee recovers marginally, up 6 paise in early trade
05-30 06:35:23.657: E/List Values(795): 43 IPS officers in UP transferred 40 times in their career
05-30 06:35:23.657: E/List Values(795): 43 IPS officers in UP transferred 40 times in their career
05-30 06:35:23.657: E/List Values(795): Allahabad HC rejects Talwars' plea to examine 14 witnesses
05-30 06:35:23.657:E/List Values(795): Defence Secretary Shashi Kant Sharma to take over as new CAG
05-30 CAG
05-30 06:35:23.691: E/List Values(795): Power of Oklahoma tornado dwarfs Hiroshima bomb
05-30 06:35:23.691: E/List Values(795): Bank fined Rs 50,000 for not repaying fixed deposit
05-30 06:35:58.607: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

Comment: Post your logcat error log

Comment: That URL look fishy. Maybe you just removed it to hide the real value? As the previous comments say the error message would help.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 2):

I dont like to sppon feed to you by giving code so check below link
Android JSON Parsing tutorial available on below link your problem will get solved using this
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I already used that example but still it shows list activity as empty..please suggest me the solution..

Comment: This should be as a comment (if you want to suggest any web/blog link). Yes it would be acceptable as answer if you include more detail with any links.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link and compare ur steps with this one...

I think u are setting response data on any control which not initialized..

https://github.com/AndroidBegin/Android-JSON-Parse-Images-and-Texts-Tutorial

Comment: How about providing link to your [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829279/how-to-fetch-data-from-json/16829418#16829418)?

Comment: Its not useful for my problem..

Comment: if u r getting data in logcat then u can easily able to set it on ur creatd views..

Comment: ya i have created text view in xml file still didnt getting the data in emulato..please suggest me..

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829279/how-to-fetch-data-from-json  this there i have answered and some more answer's are there